# Dropdown in sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown in my sidebar with the help of w3schools.com examples. For some reason, my code works fine on codepen.io and stackoverflow, but once I run it on Chrome browser, my dropdown doesn't pop down. Is there anything I could do? I have already cleared my browsing history and caches but nothing will fix it.

Could someone help me out please?

(Warning, newbie to coding)

[Code example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/qaru10/pen/MLyepz)

```js
/*Toggle sidebar*/
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}



/*Dropdown in sidebar*/
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

/*Sidebar with collapseble dropdown from w3school.com */
.sidebar{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a, .dropdown-btn{
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  width:100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover{
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
 .fa-caret-square-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <button class="dropdown-btn active">Dropdown
            <i class="far fa-caret-square-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>
        <h2>Sidebar Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Click on the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu inside the side navigation.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
        <p>Some random text..</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working on Codepen, this is maybe because your javascript is executing before the page is loaded (codepen handle that himself)

Try to run all your JS inside this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // All your JS here
}, false);
```

Comment: Hi Arthur, I don't think that is the case about the javascript execution, because my sidebar opens and closes perfectly fine. The drop down just doesn't want to pop down. In any case I have tried your solution but it did not work. All my javascript was unresponsive. Thanks for your help do.